# How to change the layer of the color block by modify the z-index style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

### Here is the description of the problem: Change the layer of the color block in JS

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    body {}
    
    #container {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: black;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }
    
    #abox {
        position: absolute;
        left: 100px;
        top: 0px;
        background-color: pink;
        width: 100px;
        height: 200px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    
    #bbox {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50px;
        top: 80px;
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 100px;
        height: 200px;
        z-index: 3;
    }
    
    #cbox {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 50px;
        background-color: blue;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    #dbox {
        position: absolute;
        left: 120px;
        top: 100px;
        background-color: green;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        z-index: 4;
    }
    
    #op {
        position: absolute;
        top: 400px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="abox" class="box"></div>
        <div id="bbox" class="box"></div>
        <div id="cbox" class="box"></div>
        <div id="dbox" class="box"></div>
        <div id="op">
            <br/>
            <label>opacity</label>
            <input id="alphalnp" type="text" value="80" />
            <input id="b1" type="button" value="setting" />
            <br/>
            <input id="b2" type="button" value="move up" />
            <input id="b3" type="button" value="move down" />
            <input id="b4" type="button" value="move to top" />
            <input id="b5" type="button" value="move to bottom" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var current_index = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $("#b1").click(function() {
            $(".box").each(function() {
                alert($(this).css("z-index"));
            });

        });

        $(".box").click(function() {
            var $box_z = $(".box");
            var box_z_length = $box_z.length;
            var $self = $(this);//get the current color block object


    


            //move up one layer
            $("#b2").click(function() {
                current_index = 0;

                var self_current_index = parseInt($self.css("z-index")) + 1;
                //$self.css("z-index", self_current_index + 1);
                $(".box").each(function() {
                    if (parseInt($(this).css("z-index")) == self_current_index) {
                        current_index = parseInt($(this).css("z-index")) - 1;
                        $(this).css("z-index", current_index);
                        //break;
                        $self.css("z-index", self_current_index);

                    }
                });


            });

            //move down one layer
            $("#b3").click(function() {
                current_index = 0;

                var self_current_index = parseInt($self.css("z-index")) - 1;
                //$self.css("z-index", self_current_index + 1);
                $(".box").each(function() {
                    if (parseInt($(this).css("z-index")) == self_current_index) {
                        current_index = parseInt($(this).css("z-index")) + 1;
                        $(this).css("z-index", current_index);
                        //break;
                        $self.css("z-index", self_current_index);

                    }
                });


            });




            //move to top
            $("#b4").click(function() {

                $(".box").each(function() {
                    if (parseInt($(this).css("z-index")) > parseInt($self.css("z-index"))) {
                        current_index = parseInt($(this).css("z-index")) - 1;
                        $(this).css("z-index", current_index);
                        // alert($(this).css("z-index"));

                    }
                });
                $self.css("z-index", "4");


            });

            //move to bottom
            $("#b5").click(function() {
                //alert($self.css("z-index"));


                $(".box").each(function() {
                    if (parseInt($(this).css("z-index")) < parseInt($self.css("z-index"))) {
                        //alert(current_index);
                        current_index = parseInt($(this).css("z-index")) + 1;
                        $(this).css("z-index", current_index);


                    }
                });
                $self.css("z-index", 1);


            });




        }); //$("#cbox,#abox,#bbox,#dbox").click(function())




    }); //document
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**the picture link about the problem([pic link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/431728/%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E6%88%AA%E5%9B%BE%202015-05-26%2022.27.08.png))**

Here is my script code with simple logic which is shown in code.But I meet some unexpected problems such as:when I click the move up bottom,it seems afflicts two block's relative postion and some other problems that i can't descibe.

What`s wrong with my code?

Comment: What are you expecting `$('.box')` to return? It's looking for elements with a `class` of "box". You seem to be trying to use a `name` attribute instead.

Comment: Your snippet is incomplete, please add some CSS so people may use the __Run code Snippet__ feature and see what's happening